# Need help in resolving the error 'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am relatively new to django and I have got an error which I am unable to understand. I have 3 models namely customer, services and uses. I want to fetch the services used by a customer. I am doing this via the uses model by querying the models(specifically using the filter method). However I am getting the following error

ValueError at /employee/view_customer/
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

the customer model contains all the details of the customers .The services model contains the details about the services(name,price). The uses model contains 2 foreign keys (customer,service). It basically stores the services used by
Here are my models

```
Customer
class Customer(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phoneno = models.IntegerField()
    emailid = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    children = models.IntegerField()
    adults = models.IntegerField()
    roomtype = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    aadharno = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    daysstayed = models.IntegerField()
    date_visited = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime())

    def __str__(self):
        if self.firstname == None:
            return ''
        else:
            return str(self.id)

Services
class Services(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    

    def __str__(self):
        if self.service_name == None:
            return ''
        else:   
            return str(self.service_name)
Uses
class Uses(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=CASCADE)
    service_id = models.ForeignKey(Services,on_delete=CASCADE)
    time_used = models.TimeField(default=timezone.localtime())

    def __str__(self):
        if self.customer == None:
            return ''
        else:   
            return str(self.customer)
```

The function at employee/view_customer

```
def view_customer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = Customer.objects.first()
        uses = Uses.objects.filter(customer_id=customer)
        services = Services.objects.filter(id=uses)
        print(services)
        return render(request,'employee/cust-info.html',{'customer':customer,'services':services}) 
    else:
     return render(request,'employee/cust-info.html')
```

I am view_customer to get all the services used by a customer. `uses = Uses.objects.filter(customer_id=customer)` is used to fetch all the rows where a particular customer is found. `services = Services.objects.filter(id=uses)` is used to get all the services pertaining to the customer.

I am using django version 3.0.7 and python version 3.7.7. I Need some help to fix this error, thank you.

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to do with `view_customer` ? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with `uses = Uses.objects.filter(customer_id=customer)`
and  `services = Services.objects.filter(id=uses)`

Comment: I am ```view_customer``` to get all the services used by a customer.   ```uses = Uses.objects.filter(customer_id=customer)``` is used to fetch all the rows where a particular customer is found. ```services = Services.objects.filter(id=uses)``` is used to get all the services pertaining to the customer.

Comment: yeah, there are multiple values of the uses instance and i want to pass them in the filter argument of the services. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I suggest learning more about how `.filter()` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code

```
uses = Uses.objects.filter(customer=customer)    
services = Services.objects.filter(uses__in=uses)
```

It is also possible to do the above in one shot

```
services = Services.objects.filter(uses__customer=customer)
```

You can read more about filtering in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters)

Comment: Thanks. The code ```services = Services.objects.filter(uses__customer=customer)``` does the job while the first code results in the same error. Can I please know the what does ```uses__customer``` actually mean?

Comment: Django ORM supports filtering in both directions through a ForeighKey. it also supports chaining of filters using double underscore. I highly recommend you to go through the documentation. There are so many cool things like this possible with Django ORM